# How to pause VoiceOver when application in foreground and continue when application goes to background

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have application that contain text to speech functionality also with voice recognition. so when I start application VoiceOver and and text to speech both are overwrite my text. is there any way to stop or pause VoiceOver on application launch and continue VoiceOver when application moved to background or killed by user.

I don't have much idea about this but I did search it on stackoverflow and I found some solutions but it's didn't work for me.

I tried below code but it didn't stop or pause VoiceOver speech.

```
view.accessibilityTraits = .allowsDirectInteraction
view.isAccessibilityElement = true
```

Comment: This is user configurable, and not something you should really change on someone's behalf. If the user wants, they can tap the control key to pause/resume speech, or toggle mute with keycommander enabled, <right option> v